# Spread figure over two pages (with Tufte)

Tags: graphics, floats, tufte, wide-image

Is there a way to make figures wider than a page with the Tufte class? I have a few figures that are wide and would fit well spread over two pages.

There's a [very neat solution for a spread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23860/how-to-include-a-picture-over-two-pages-left-part-on-left-side-right-on-right) which does not work with Tufte. Apparently `figure*` would be necessary instead of `figure` to handle margins, but it's not trivial to fix. A fix to that code would already be nice enough, but even better if instead of a full spread on both pages it could cover 100% of one page and an arbitrary part of the other (such as 30%). I don't mind a workaround that requires splitting the image in two.

Comment: IIRC, tufte always puts the margin on the right side, so all you should have to do is replace figure with figure*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is not quite perfect, but it's working. I am not quite sure why there are margins that require `adjustwidth` (and what margin is that, so I had to adjust the value manually).

```
\begin{figure*}[t!]
   \begin{adjustwidth}{-15mm}{-15mm}
      \adjustbox{trim=0 0 {.5\width} 0,clip}{\includegraphics[width=2\paperwidth]{image.jpg}}%
  \end{adjustwidth}
\end{figure*}
\afterpage{
  \begin{figure*}[t!]
    \begin{adjustwidth}{-15mm}{-15mm}
       \adjustbox{trim={.5\width} 0 0 0,clip}{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{image.jpg}}      
        \caption{This image is a two page spread.}%
        \label{fig:label}%
      \end{adjustwidth}
  \end{figure*}
}
```

Besides not having the syntactic sugar from [the other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23860/how-to-include-a-picture-over-two-pages-left-part-on-left-side-right-on-right), including make sure it starts on a left page, which is not difficult to replicate, the difference here is that the image is not aligned to the top of the page, but the top of the text. I don't mind that.

Regarding the partial spread, that would be more difficult. It'd need something like the [wide margin figure solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/561790/making-a-margin-figure-wider-than-the-margin) coupled with this here. So it's left as an exercise to the reader, and if you do solve it post the answer.